# Django v1.5, TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: django, django-templates

In settings.py I've chosen to run with sqlite3 and name this database database.db.

```
from blog_app.views import oneView, anotherView
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^one/$', oneView),
    url(r'^another/$', anotherView),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^django_project/', include('django_project.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and my views.py looks like this

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def oneView(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"content":"Hello World, from oneView"})

def anotherView(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"content":"Hello Again, from anotherView"})
```

my dir to the index.html is blog/blog_app/templates/index.html. since by standard the settings.py file says this:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

I think it's weird that it says that my index.html file cannot be found. isn't it looking in the correct directory?

nonetheless, I only get a "TemplateDoesNotExist at /one/" error when I try to go to 
127.0.0.1:8000/one/ or 127.0.0.1:8000/another/

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this in your settings.py

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)
BLOG_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "blog_app)
TEMPLATES_PATH = os.path.join(BLOG_PATH, "templates")

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATES_PATH,
)
```

The error usually is due to incorrectly configured templates directory

Comment: I know I shouldn't use this space for thanks, but here you come with a anonymous username and deliver the perfect answer! It works now. U rock

Comment: @Dolcens the answer is according to my interpretation of your directory structure..if it does not work please provide the structure of you Django application

Comment: Dont forget to upvote..I am kinda new on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact error message? (debug informations)

I use this kind of configuration for templates:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
)
```

They are accessible in the `templates` folder of your django application (aside `manage.py`), in a sub-folder named following the application used if set (it's not your case for the urls you provided us with).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out! I tried your suggestion and got the following error msg:
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined

Comment: And without this line the full error msg is (current):

http://pastebin.com/qVSB5SJT